# Is it possible to duck type an ActiveRecord ORM?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle, sqlite, activerecord, orm

In an app I'm working on, the production database is Oracle and the development db is sqlite.

Most of the app code is high level ActiveRecord, but there is some custom sql for reporting.  This sql varies depending on the backend db.

Rather than extending the ORM and adapters, or writing if statements throughout the application, is it possible to duck type the connection such that something like the below code is possible:

```
if Archive.connection.supports_function?("EXTRACT")
  Archive.select("extract(year from created_at)")...
else
  Archive.select("strftime('%Y', created_at)")...
end
```

Comment: one little detail - "duck typing" does NOT mean "ask the code if it can quack like a duck." It means "just let the code waddle and quack, whether it's a duck or not."

Comment: Are you sure about that phlip? can you point me to some resources explaining that.  Everything I've read on duck typing always begins with: "Does it walk like a duck? does it quack like a duck? If so, then it must be a duck!"

Comment: The opposite of Duck Typing is a Java Interface, where you explicitly list the things that all waterfowl do, whether they are Ducks or Loons (which are a different clade). Then functions which need waddling and quacking declare this interface type in their interface. "Duck Typing" means you don't declare an interface, you just pass the object, and call its .waddle() and .quack() methods. Querying what methods an object presents is closer to static typing; duck typists simply prefer a function explode if it calls a method that does not exist

Comment: Matt's answer, which I up-voted, simply asks "are you a duck?" Also not duck-typing.

Comment: To me, duck typing is all about behavior not type.  I don't care if you're a duck(type), but whether you can waddle or quack(behavior), just as you say, philp.  And code should be defensive and ask if the object can waddle or quack.  So, in this instance: can my adapter "extract"? or can it "strftime"? so i think i win this duck-swinging contest...that's a joke :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be completely misunderstanding your requirement but you can check the adapter and change the code used for a method easily enough. 
If you want to add a new extract method to activerecord that behaves in two ways for example:

```
# config/initializers/active_record_extract.rb
class ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.extract_agnostic(oracle_column, default_column)
    if ActiveRecord::Base.connection.instance_values["config"][:adapter].include?('oracle')    
      return self.select("extract(#{column1} from created_at)")...
    end

    self.select("strftime(#{default_column}, created_at)")...  
  end
end

# Usage:
Archive.extract_agnostic("year", "%Y")
```

Obviously this isn't perfect but should get you started?

I don't think rails can tell you if your adapter understands a command, but you could always try wrapping the command you want in a `begin/rescue`:

```
begin
  self.select("extract(year from created_at)")...
rescue # the above failed, try something else
  self.select("strftime('%Y', created_at)")...  
end
```

Comment: great solutions matt, i'm thinking I might combine both approaches such that upon application boot, it runs a dummy sql command to see if an exception is raised("select extract(year from created_at) from users") and then sets a flag on AR telling clients(subclasses) of AR which to use in the #agnostic call.  Is it possible to mark your answer as accepted but then append it with my final code for others to see?

Comment: @PeterP. Absolutely, the common approach is to accept the most helpful answer then later add your solution as a separate answer or edit to your question explaining your adapted approach. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you run an Oracle database for your development environment..? Scratch that - I don't want to know.

Use `create_function` to plug an `extract()` method into your SQLite:

http://rdoc.info/github/luislavena/sqlite3-ruby/SQLite3/Database#create_function-instance_method

(And good luck doing THAT in Oracle!;)

Comment: the whole point of duck-typing is to not care or think about the underlying adapter.  I just need to know if the adapter behaves like a standard sql adapter(uses strftime) or uses proprietary sql(extract/oracle).  Custom sql prevents database portability, but duck-typing it can mitigate this when its unavoidable.

Comment: then the problem with ActiveRecord supplying a `supports_function?` is each SQL dialect has zillions of tiny differences, with function-like things, so even if one SQL supported `EXTRACT()`, another might not support `EXTRACT(YEAR)` (for example), so there's no way to make such a method completely useful...

Comment: I agree, however, I see this as more of an application level extension that just needs to support the functions the application cares about rather than a framework extension.